# rich:editor rerender problem

Tags: java, jsf, tinymce, richfaces

i have used rich:editor to show file content.If i use h:commandlink for display the editor works fine.If i use the a4j:commandlink and rerender the editor its not working properly.I got the following script error,

tinyMCE is null or not an object and tinyMCE_Editor is null or not an object.

How can i resolve this?Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known tinyMCE problem which happens if you use it with AJAX. 
The workaround is in [the first comment in their forum](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=4673&p=1).